# Limit number of rooms Django channels urls

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I was looking for a way to limit the number of rooms avaliable on a Django channels chat app.
I can't figure out how to code this, I wonder if I can do this directly on `urls.py` or maybe in  `views.py`, during the routing.

Here is my `urls.py`:

```
path('app/<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
```

and my `views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='main:login') 
def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, 'app/room.html', {
        'room_name': room_name,
    })
```

I can't figure out the way of limit the number of rooms avaliable (only avaliable the rooms within a lis) so that a user would be redirected to app_main when tries to access a non avaliable room

Comment: I actualy add  `if not room_name in list_rooms:  return redirect('app:app_index')` to my `views.py` so it check whether the `room_name` exists in a list or not and then redirects to the `app_index` if not

Comment: I don't know if there would be another way to improve that but it currently works fine